# Joomla, Multiple layouts in a single template

Tags: templates, joomla

I tired the joomla IRC but no one ever talks in there :(, heres the issue i have.

i have a site that have 3 diff types of layouts.

1. home page
2. all the other pages
3. portfolio page

im using joomla 1.6

all i can see is the index.php file on the root of my template folder.
hwo can i create 3 diff layouts in side a single template folder and assign these to diff pages (menu itmes).

Answer (score 1):

From : http://docs.joomla.org/Introduction_to_Joomla!_templates#Assigning_more_than_one_template_for_the_Front-end

Assigning more than one template for the Front-end

Joomla! gives you the option of switching between two or more templates on the Front-end. This is done with "Menu Assignment", so you can set different templates for each menu or only a menu item.

Click on: Extensions -> Template Manager

You see your installed templates, now choose a template which is not set as your default one. Click on the template name or hit the radio button to the left of the template name, and click "Edit" on the toolbar. You now see the page "Template: [ Edit ]", click the radio button "Select from List" in the "Menu Assignment" block and choose the menu items on which the template will be shown. Click "Save" on the toolbar and you´re done.

[image]

Comment: is there a way I can ahve all my 3 diff layout files inside as single template folder, its just easier to manage than having 3 different template folders.

Comment: Check for the itemid of the article and put it one file or include something like this

global $Itemid;

if ( ** Item ID Home ** == 6 ) : 
....
else :
include default
endif;

Answer (score 0):

You can assign different templates to different menu items using the admin backend of Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla admin, go to Extensions->Template Manager

Find your template in the list. Mark the checkbox in its front and click the Duplicate button on the toolbar (where the new, edit, delete, options, etc buttons are).

You can edit the template style by clicking on it.

Editing means that you can change it's parameters, and you can assign it directly to menu items.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need multiple templates to accomplish multiple layouts. If your template is coded correctly, then module positions that are not being used will collapse and not show up in the code at all. You then control what modules show up on a particular page by assigning the modules to the various menu items. That way you can control the layout of each page with a single template.

For even more control you can make use of the page class suffix that is available in the menu item parameters. You may need to add a bit of code to utilize the page class suffix, but it allows you to control the CSS per page of the site so you can totally control the layout depending on which menu item you are on.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so figured out how todo this.

on the index.php of the template there is a method being called [templatename]_body_classes();
using that i figured out which page im actually in.

and if it retuns "home" i included the layout for the home page, and so on for portfolio and for anypage thats not home or portfolio.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer on the same question in this tutorial. This is the way you can create different styles (but not templates) in Joomla 1.6 or 1.7:

http://www.own-it.nl/creating-different-styles-for-your-joomla-template